# Select data based on dropdownlist selected item in Asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing an application using Asp.net MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6 which contains a Product Model as follows:

```
[Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public float Stock { get; set; }
```

In my controller I am populating the list of Product:

```
DemoDBContext db = new DemoDBContext();
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var productList = db.Products.ToList();
        ViewBag.Products = productList;
        return View();
    }
```

and my view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    var productList = ViewBag.Products;
}
 <td>
    @Html.DropDownList("Products", new SelectList(productList, "ProductId", "Name"), "-- Select Product --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                <span class="error">Item name required</span>
  </td>
```

What i am trying to accomplish is whenever i select a **Product** from **dropdownlist**, the corresponding **Stock** of that product will be shown in a **htmltextinput**. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controler, you can wait for the ProductId:

```
 public ActionResult Index(int ProductId = 0)
    {
         var productList = db.Products.ToList();
         ViewBag.Products = productList;
         if(ProductId!=0)
         {
           //do the logic to get the stock
         }
         return View();
    }
```

In the view, it is ok, just add the script, that sends the ProductId as a query string parameter:

```
<td>
@Html.DropDownList("Products", new SelectList(productList, "ProductId", "Name"), "-- Select Product --", new { @class = "form-control" })
            <span class="error">Item name required</span>
```

```
<script>
 $(function () {
            $('#Products').change(function () {
                window.location = "Index?ProductId=" + $(this).val();
            });
        });
</script>
```

I would personaly use a ViewModel like:

```
 public class Product
    {
        [Display(Name="Choose product:")]
        public int Product { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Stock:")]
        public string Stock { get; set; }
        public List<Products> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

And the controller like:

```
 public ActionResult Index(int ProductId = 0)
        {
            var model = new Product
            {
                Products = db.Products.ToList(),
                Stock = ProductId != 0 ? db.Products.Where(x=>x.ProductId == ProductId).FirstOrDefault().Stock : null
            };
            return View(model);
        }
```

And last, the view like:

```
@model Models.Product
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<table>
   <tr>
    <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Product)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Product, new SelectList(Model.Products, "ProductId", "Name"), "-- Select Product --", new { onchange = "return ToggleViewItems();" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Product, string.Empty, new { @class = "" })
    </td>
    <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Stock)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Stock)
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
   $(function () {
        $('#Product').change(function () {
              window.location = "Index?ProductId=" + $(this).val();
         });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems too complicated for me to add another viewmodel and deal with it. Can you please simplify the solution?

Comment: I checked your code and it is not selecting the stock based on the product selected

Comment: What is it selecting? Does the Stock have a value? Or it's null?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Jquery to handle the DropdownList events. See sample for onChange listener. [Jquery OnChange](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

Then, you can send Async request to server to get some data or do some client-side tasks using Jquery or native Javascript.

Comment: `<script>
                            $("#Products").change(function () {
                                alert($('option:selected', $(this)).text());
                            });
                        </script>` Currently i'm doing this and can't understand what to do next.